# Не могу прочитать файл в отдельном классе андроид

Tags: java, android, файлы, filestream

Есть следующий класс для записи и чтение файла (внутренняя память телефона)

```
import android.content.Context;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class LoadData {

    public void loadData (){
    }

    // переменная в которой записано название файла что представляет собой локальную строку json
    // или локальную базу
    private String FILENAME = "jsonmytest";

    //метод для сохранение строки json в файл (создание локальной базы)
    protected void write(String answer) {
        try {
            // отрываем поток для записи
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)));
            // пишем данные
            bw.write(answer);
            // закрываем поток
            bw.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // метод для чтения строки json из файла
    public String readFile() {
        String str = "";
        try {
            // открываем поток для чтения
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput(FILENAME)));
            // читаем содержимое
            str = br.readLine();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

методы openFileOutput и openFileInput подсвечивает красным и при наведении пишет Cannot resovle method 'openFileInput(java.long.String)'
Естественно все библиотеки импортированы.

Точно такой же код методов read и write работает в классе MainActivity но это нужно вынести загрузку в другой класс.
Помогите пожалуйста, никак не могу понять в чём ошибка.

Comment: `openFileOutput()` и `openFileInput()` методы класса `Context`. Активити - наследник класса контекста, а ваш класс - нет, поэтому в активити эти методы работают, а в вашем - нет.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передавайте context в конструктор и используйте его как показано в коде ниже.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;


public class LoadData {

  private  Context context;

    public LoadData(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    // переменная в которой записано название файла что представляет собой локальную строку json
    // или локальную базу
    private String FILENAME = "jsonmytest";

    //метод для сохранение строки json в файл (создание локальной базы)
    protected void write(String answer) {
        try {
            // отрываем поток для записи
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)));
            // пишем данные
            bw.write(answer);
            // закрываем поток
            bw.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // метод для чтения строки json из файла
    public String readFile() {
        String str = "";
        try {
            // открываем поток для чтения
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.openFileInput(FILENAME)));
            // читаем содержимое
            str = br.readLine();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Так же советую ознакомится [Android Context](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/context.php)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.
Вызываю так:
LoadData load = new LoadData(this);
String str = load.readFile();